# Keyboard shortcut to kill uWSGI process in mac terminal

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, docker, macbook-pro, uwsgi

```
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 5 seconds on interpreter 0x56549c79e7d0 pid: 12 (default app)
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 12)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 20, cores: 1)
```

The above is the output on my terminal after the `docker run` command to run a flask API. I can open another terminal and use `docker exec` command to test the endpoints. But, how can I kill the process running in the terminal of uWSGI process? Ctrl+Z, Ctrl+Q, Ctrl+X, Ctrl+C, Cmd+Q, Cmd+X, Cmd+Q, Cmd+X doesn't work.

Also, please share if I am making any naive mistake here in the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `startup.sh` you can add `exec` before `uwsgi`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
service nginx start
exec uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

After that you will be able to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop it.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55854081/260238)